# I can´t page break or print 2 pages with printThis.js plugin

Tags: printthis

Im using the printThis.js plugin to print a page, but I can´t get the page break to work. It is only printing one page, even if the page is longer than a A4 and I use a page break.

```
<input type="button" value="Print" class="noprint" onclick="$('.printable,#break_page').printThis();">
```

My page looks like this.

```
<div class="printable">
Some content....

<div id="break_page" style="page-break-after:always; display:block; position:relative;"></div>

Some more content...

</div>
```

So why isn´t it deviding it in 2 pages when I try to print? Any input appreciated, thanks.

SOLVED. I had a overflow:hidden that caused the problem, so now it works.

Comment: A couple of notes - there's no need to indicate `#break-page` because it is contained in the `.printable` container. Additionally, there may be CSS on your page conflicting with print layouts - you can try `printContainer: false`, which only grabs the content of the container, not the container itself. Additionally, I'm the author of printThis and if you would like more help in github or here, you really need to provide more details of your issue and things you have tried.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I had a overflow:hidden that caused the problem :-) So it is working now.